# GD Library image resize lowers quality

Tags: php, image, gd

I am trying to merge resized design to a background based on the width/height which defined while uploading background to database but when I try to resize an image to a lower sizes/pixels, like if it is 1/3 of the source image(because source image pixels can be lower compared to high quality design), resized image loses quality a lot when zoomed. Is there any way to improve quality when resized to a lower sizes/pixels because page will have a zoom feature to looking designs closer.

My resize code:

```
    $resize = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagesavealpha($resize, true);
    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($resize, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($resize, 0, 0, $trans_colour);
    $source_image = imagecreatefrompng("$path1");
    $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
    $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);
    imagecopyresampled($resize, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);
```

Some example of high,medium and low quality resized&merged examples(please take a look closer to eagle design):

[high quality image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN3UX.jpg)

[medium quality image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lgOO.jpg)

[low quality image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFwbX.jpg)

I don't know if my resize method is the best method for resizing and also I don't know if this is the best quality I can get because loss of quality is expected when resizing to lower pixels.

Also if anyone interested about only resized designs without merged with background;

[high quality design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcnFI.png)

[medium quality design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVgBj.png)

[low quality design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyEom.png)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're actually doing. You show the code for resizing the image, but speak about merging two images.
As a reference can you share one before and after resize image? The 3 images you shared all contain different pictures and aren't just resized versions, so there's nothing to compare and understand your problem from these.

Comment: Once you reduce the size of an image to, say, 1/3 of its size, you lose the data contained in those missing pixels. So when you zoom in on that smaller image, it will never contain the quality of the original.

Comment: @Mastacheata there is also resized version on the bottom like high/medium/low quality design ( sorry for not being clear enough)

Comment: @kmoser , so this is actually best quality I can get and improving not that possibile due to data loss which is expected ?

Comment: Missing data is missing data. Unless you're willing to get into complex image restoration algorithms, you can't get back what you have lost.

Comment: @batuhankaya97 The first 3 links are either the resized or the original versions. The other 3 links include only the logo you insert into the images, but don't show how the final images looked before/after resizing.

Comment: Also: The basic resizing algorithm is just throw away every n-th pixel. There are other algorithms that would rather try to separate your image into uniform blocks before resizing and will adjust color of the surrounding pixels to give an illusion of retaining more information. This works worse the more fine details an image has and needs to retain. Color gradients are a great example for how these algorithms can improve the quality. White noise on the other hand is a a bad example.

Comment: @Mastacheata first 3 links are the resized/final versions, high quality image's resized logo is high quality design, medium image's logo is medium quality design and low image's logo is low quality design. First 3 is resized(all of the logos has different sizes due to their pixels; first image's logo 1000x1000, medium image's logo 480x480 and low image's logo 341x341 resized) then merged with background, last 3 links are just resized versions before merging with background and also thanks for the comments, really appreciated